How to query XML in SQL to find an element by partial text() match
Given the following XML in a table column:
<UserFields>
  <UserField>
    <Name>UserName</Name>
    <Value>test_user</Value>
  </UserField>
  <UserField>
    <Name>Age</Name>
    <Value>24</Value>
  </UserField>
  <UserField>
    <Name>Password</Name>
    <Value>test1234!</Value>
  </UserField>
  <UserField>
    <Name>AgentPassword</Name>
    <Value>1234Test!</Value>
  </UserField>
</UserFields>
<ActionAttributes>
  <Action>
   <Name>LoginPassword</Name>
   <Value>Test123!</Value>
  </Action>
</ActionAttributes>

I want to query the XML to find any element that has a <Name> node that has text() containing the word password and replace the text of the <Value> node with asterisks.  In the sample, there would be three replacements and I would wind up with the following XML.
<UserFields>
  <UserField>
    <Name>UserName</Name>
    <Value>test_user</Value>
  </UserField>
  <UserField>
    <Name>Age</Name>
    <Value>24</Value>
  </UserField>
  <UserField>
    <Name>Password</Name>
    <Value>********</Value>
  </UserField>
  <UserField>
    <Name>AgentPassword</Name>
    <Value>********</Value>
  </UserField>
</UserFields>
<ActionAttributes>
  <Action>
   <Name>LoginPassword</Name>
   <Value>********</Value>
  </Action>
</ActionAttributes>

I was able to come up with this:
SET @MyDoc.modify('
  replace value of (//UserField[Name="Password"]/Value/text())[1]
  with "********"
');

The problem with this code is:

It hardcodes the name of the parent element ('UserField').
It hardcodes the name of the value of <Name> so it only finds 'password' and not other variations.

In English, I would say:
"For any node that has <Name> and <Value> child nodes.  If child node <Name> contains the word 'password', then replace the text of the child node <Value> with asterisks."

Try //UserField[contains(Name,"Password")] or //UserField[Name="Password" or Name="AgentPassword"]

The or option defeats the purpose -- trying to avoid having to list all different cases where password might be in the name.  The contains option yields an error [modify()]: 'contains()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

It's a design limitation of mssql XML implementation I believe. The or won't probably work either since the [1] at the end might be limiting the update to 1 and only 1 node. Same if there were multiple Password type nodes.

Don't think sql server xml modify method can replace multiple nodes, you'll have to probably parse and recreate the xml with the fields replaced manually. As usual, the question attacks the wrong problem though, why working on manipulating the xml, when you can work on the process generating such xml

@siggemannen -- Easier to trap it in one spot than trying to comb a system that has been cobbled upon over the past 15 years and find every possible combination of calls that might be made to insert. :-)

Well, surely you don't store XML but shred it down anyway

As many already mentioned, SQL Server doesn't support multi-element XML update in one shot.
Please try the following solution based on SQL Server's XQuery and its FLWOR expression.
SQL #1
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xml_data XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xml_data) VALUES
(N'<UserFields>
    <UserField>
        <Name>UserName</Name>
        <Value>test_user</Value>
    </UserField>
    <UserField>
        <Name>Age</Name>
        <Value>24</Value>
    </UserField>
    <UserField>
        <Name>Password</Name>
        <Value>test1234!</Value>
    </UserField>
    <UserField>
        <Name>AgentPassword</Name>
        <Value>1234Test!</Value>
    </UserField>
</UserFields>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- just to see
SELECT * 
    , xml_data.query('<UserFields>{
        for $x in /UserFields/*
        return element UserField {
            if (contains(($x/Name/text())[1],"Password")) then
                ($x/*[local-name() != "Value"], element Value {"********"})
            else $x/*
        }
    }</UserFields>') AS modified_xml
FROM @tbl;

-- real deal
UPDATE @tbl
SET xml_data = xml_data.query('<UserFields>{
    for $x in /UserFields/*
    return element UserField {
        if (contains(($x/Name/text())[1],"Password")) then
            ($x/*[local-name() != "Value"], element Value {"********"})
        else $x/*
    }
}</UserFields>');

-- test
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

SQL #2
For the changed XML in the question we can use a different approach.
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xml_data XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xml_data) VALUES
(N'<UserFields>
  <UserField>
    <Name>UserName</Name>
    <Value>test_user</Value>
  </UserField>
  <UserField>
    <Name>Age</Name>
    <Value>24</Value>
  </UserField>
  <UserField>
    <Name>Password</Name>
    <Value>test1234!</Value>
  </UserField>
  <UserField>
    <Name>AgentPassword</Name>
    <Value>1234Test!</Value>
  </UserField>
</UserFields>
<ActionAttributes>
  <Action>
   <Name>LoginPassword</Name>
   <Value>Test123!</Value>
  </Action>
</ActionAttributes>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

DECLARE @ReplaceWith VARCHAR(10) = '*********';
DECLARE @UPDATE_STATUS BIT = 1;

WHILE @UPDATE_STATUS > 0 
BEGIN
    UPDATE t
    SET xml_data.modify('replace value of 
        (/*/*[contains((Name/text())[1], "Password") and Value/text()!=sql:variable("@ReplaceWith")]/Value/text())[1] 
        with sql:variable("@ReplaceWith")')
    FROM @tbl AS t
    WHERE xml_data.exist('/*/*[contains((Name/text())[1], "Password") and Value/text()!=sql:variable("@ReplaceWith")]')=1;
        
    SET @UPDATE_STATUS = @@ROWCOUNT;
    PRINT @UPDATE_STATUS;
END;

-- after
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

SQL #3
This one is for the SQL Server variable/parameter of XML data type.
DECLARE @xml_data XML =
N'<Event>
    <CaseNumber>PD200731245151</CaseNumber>
    <City>
        <CaseNumber>PD200731245770</CaseNumber>
    </City>
</Event>';

DECLARE @ReplaceWith VARCHAR(10) = '*********';

WHILE (@xml_data.exist('//*[contains((./text())[1], "PD")]') = 1)
BEGIN 
    SET @xml_data.modify('replace value of 
            (//*[contains((./text())[1], "PD")]/text())[1] 
            with sql:variable("@ReplaceWith")');
END;

-- test
SELECT @xml_data;


SQL #2 did the job!  Thanks tons.  For what its worth, I changed the code slightly to enable replacement of values regardless of the casing of "password".  ...[contains(upper-case(Name/text())[1]), "PASSWORD") ...

@RHarris, good to hear that the proposed solution is working for you!

Is there any way to tell it to check at any level?  Right now the (/*/*[contains... syntax forces it to begin looking two levels deep.  Occasionally, I find XML where we may be 3 levels deep or 1 level deep.

Yes, it is possible by switching to the following XPath expression: (//*[contains... in both spots.

Also, please up-vote my suggestion to Microsoft: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0 And don't miss my multiple comments.

One last question, SQL XML is not my strong suite.  Is there a way to do the replace as you've done without using a table.  For example, if I turned this into a stored proc that receives XML, can I somehow work off of the incoming parameter instead of storing the XML in a table?

I added SQL #3 as an example.

You're awesome!  Thanks so much.

Glad to be helpful. Please don't forget to up-vote my suggestion to Microsoft: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

XPath expression must define a single node

Expression1


Identifies a node whose value is to be updated. It must identify only a single node. That is, Expression1 must be a static singleton. If the XML is typed, the type of the node must be a simple type. When multiple nodes are selected, an error is raised.

Using SQL variables could be an alternative to avoid hardcoding the predicate in the expression.
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(50) = 'Password';
DECLARE @NewValue VARCHAR(50) = '********';
SET @MyDoc.modify('
replace value of (//UserField[Name = sql:variable("@Name")]/Value/text())[1]
with sql:variable("@NewValue")
');

Iterating possible values
DECLARE @myDoc XML;
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @parent VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @NewValue VARCHAR(50) = '********';
DECLARE @rowid int;

DECLARE @tnames TABLE(
rowid iNT,
names VARCHAR(50),
parent VARCHAR(50)
);

SET @myDoc = '<root>
<UserFields>
  <UserField>
    <Name>UserName</Name>
    <Value>test_user</Value>
  </UserField>
  <UserField>
    <Name>Age</Name>
    <Value>24</Value>
  </UserField>
  <UserField>
    <Name>Password</Name>
    <Value>test1234!</Value>
  </UserField>
  <UserField>
    <Name>AgentPassword</Name>
    <Value>1234Test!</Value>
  </UserField>
</UserFields>
<ActionAttributes>
  <Action>
   <Name>LoginPassword</Name>
   <Value>Test123!</Value>
  </Action>
</ActionAttributes>
</root>
';

--SELECT @myDoc;

INSERT INTO @tnames (rowid, names, parent)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.xname) AS ROWID, T.xname.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') as names, T.xname.value('(local-name(.))[1]', 'varchar(max)') as parent
FROM @myDoc.nodes('//*[Name[contains(., "Password")]]') T(xname); 

SELECT * FROM @tnames;

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @tnames) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @rowid = rowid, @Name = names, @parent= parent FROM @tnames;
    
    SET @MyDoc.modify('
    replace value of (//*[local-name() = sql:variable("@parent")][Name = sql:variable("@Name")]/Value/text())[1]
    with sql:variable("@NewValue")
    ');
    
    DELETE FROM @tnames where rowid = @rowid;

    --SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.xname) AS ROWID, T.xname.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') as names, T.xname.value('(Value/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') as value 
    --FROM @myDoc.nodes('//*[local-name() = sql:variable("@parent")][Name = sql:variable("@Name")]') T(xname);
    
END

